# Sort a table with multiple <tbody> in jquery table sorter 2.0

Tags: jquery, sorting, tablesorter

I have a table lets say

```
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Sam</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Alex</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How Can i sort this using tablesorter 2.0 if i use `$("#myTbale").tablesorter();`
It only sort a single tbody.

Comment: Please post a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

I have a [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) which will sort each tbody separately. If you have a tbody that you don't want to sort, then add the class name contained within the [`cssInfoBlock` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#cssinfoblock) - default is `tablesorter-infoOnly`.

```
<tbody class="tablesorter-infoOnly">
  <tr>
    <th>The contents of this tbody</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>will not be sorted</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I want to sort tbodies not tr inside each tbody. iwant to sort tbodies using td inside each tbody. like in the above example i want to use name. to sort tbody.

Comment: Ahh ok, I had [a request for this ability](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/pull/195) but I never got around to implementing it due to time constraints; sorry. The pull request I linked wasn't working as intended.